# Programatically disable part of a website's CSS

Tags: html, css

I know it's probably not possible, but I want to be able to create a file of some kind that will automatically disable part of a website's CSS. Basically, when I go to the site, I want this to be disabled instantly:

[image]

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/) – they have a browser plugin called 'Stylish' which you can use to apply custom CSS to a particular site. For example, the CSS style that would do what you want here is:

```
.roundfield .usertext-edit textarea {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this for **all website**, you will need to [Build a Chrome Extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), or [Firefox Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension), those will help you to access every website's html/js/css. Then you can simple use a small javascript to disable everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using jQuery disable the elements on page load or set the css as empty.

```
$(document).ready(){
  $('#target_element).css();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Chrome. You can edit Chrome's user style sheet and override the style of any site. Put the URL about:version in the search bar and note the "profile path". Browse to the profile path (e.g. `C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets`) and in your profile folder open the user style sheets folder. Look for a file called custom.css and add your styles (e.g. `.roundfield .usertext-edit textarea { /* your css here*/}`). Note that you may need to use the dreaded `!important` declaration in your rule to override the rules of the site you're targeting.

Answer (score -1):

yes, it can be achieved with javascript/jQuery, on page load target all elements with the specific class and set their background to none.